What’s with the new cookie banner with "legitimate interests" only on certain SE sites?
Stack Overflow has a new cookie banner/setting page which includes somewhat hidden "legitimate interests". Which also have to be objected to individually, not by using the "necessary only "button:

The newdesign adds 5 new buttons you have to press which scatterd within "Peformance Cookies" (3) and "Targeting Cookies "(2).
The "Necessary cookies only" button is misleading in this design as it does not apply the objections:

One has to press each Object to Legitimate Interests.
 But the scope is limited this Meta site, SE sites like https://dba.stackexchange.com/ and stackoverflow.blog still have the regular banner/setting page.
The new banner appars to be on several SE sites aswell as per this comment.
There haven't been any announcements on the SO-Meta or this Meta about any such change/public test. Also the implementation of the "legitimate interests" (from my limited understanding of the topic) does look like a dark pattern.
Trying to replicate the issue today in a private browser tab failed:

The connection is the same, I am logged in in both sessions and both show the version rev 2024.5.24.9787.
Now the trigger for what version is shown is not really clear. This is however a different design from Cookie consent going down hill.

Possible dupe: Cookie consent going down hill. It's still unclear for the criteria to show this version of the cookie banner, probably only applies to the GDPR area.

It appears to be another design and whether it's shown is not region specific (or at least not only based on that).

The hidden "legitimate interests" settings are apparently not limited to stackoverflow, I was able to see them on several other stackexchange sites as well, e.g. on https://cooking.stackexchange.com/ , The list of partners, and which partners have such a setting, appears to vary by site

The modal that you see was previously announced, during the update to our cookie consent modal that was dictated by the Interactive Advertising Bureau’s Transparency & Consent Framework (TCF) EU 2.2 requirements which can be found here.
When serving ads to EEA/UK users, re-consent is required and EEA/UK users see the TCF 2.2 compliant template, whereas others will continue to see the standard. If a visitor’s IP address is unknown, then our standard consent model will deploy.
In compliance with IAB TCF framework requirements and in addition to complying with relevant data protection laws, we do not store information or access information on a user’s device without consent, or process personal data related to a user without a legal basis to do so. We also shall indicate its legitimate interest for processing – where applicable.
The objection to legitimate interests selection does not apply to “Necessary cookies only” due to the ‘strictly necessary’ exemption. When the “Necessary cookies only” option is selected, it does not object to legitimate interest processing. An objection to legitimate interests requests clear affirmative action, as is dictated by TCF 2.2.

An additional question has been raised a while ago regarding this topic. Please add an answer as there appears to be no movement on that topic. Should that not be possible, at least a comment as to when an answer can be expected. Also regarding your answer I do not see how "the ‘strictly necessary’ exemption" applies here? After all the website works even if I object.
